# Magmi Import Attribute on Create Only

Tags: magento, magmi

Related to a previous question, is there a way to get Magmi to only import the value of an attribute if it's creating the product, but if it's updating it automatically switch to ignoring it?

We've got clients who expand on the description in their import files using the admin section, and we need a way to accommodate this.

Edit: To clarify, I'm basically looking for a flag which I can use so that fields can be ignored when a product is being updated while running an import with the create flag (rather than update or xcreate). While I could do it by running magmi twice (once as xcreate then once as update), it seems like there should be a better way of managing this

Comment: I'm not sure I've fully understood but you can have different profiles, so do different things such as only importing some columns. Have you looked at http://www.blinkdata.com/magmi-import-limiter/ too?

Comment: Unfortunately the script needs to be automated via the command line, so I need a way to automatically detect if a particular product is being imported or updated

Comment: On reflection I could actually use this, but I'd rather not have to run Magmi multiple times every time the stock file is updated if I can avoid it. Also thanks for the link for the import limiter, the documentation and wiki links on the Magmi control panel don't work for that plugin (at least the version I've got)

Comment: I believe you can run Magmi from the command line although I haven't (yet) tried myself.

Comment: Already had that working, it was really just the control of what was entered when it did an update vs an import. Switched behavior to run twice, once for creation and once for update, and used different profiles for each so I could use import limiter to control what attributes get modified on update

Comment: You could write a simple plugin that detects if the product already exists, then fill the description column with the `__MAGMI_IGNORE__` flag which tells Magmi to ignore the data in that column.

Comment: Going with Pedro's idea, it seems to do the job and it doesn't actually add a noticeable delay to the import either which was what I was worried about